# Rails 4 API - Nil location provided. Can't build URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-deployment, server, rails-api

I just want to make my api check if entry exists, and then returns/responds with a `true` or `false` (`boolean`)

controller

```
def checkBus
    if Bus.exists?(:name => params[:driver_name])
        respond_with true
    else
        respond_with false
    end
end
```

but i am getting this error `ArgumentError (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use render:

```
def checkBus
    if Bus.exists?(:name => params[:driver_name])
        render text: 'true'
    else
        render text: 'false'
    end
end
```

hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.8/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with

You can only use `respond_with` with resource.

Depending on your use case, one option would be to use :

```
render :text => 'true'
```

Comment: um sorry but where should use `render` ?